# How to apply random component to html Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I wonder how to apply a random component to an html in Angular. Let's presume, that I have a three components with different html-css:

```
export class Component1{}
export class Component2{}
export class Component3{}
```

I want the html of app root to have one of those component's element inside.
app root HTML:

```
<app-randomComponent></app-randomComponent>
```

The main idea was to store all Components inside data structure and get it from there. What's the propper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should likely go with the [`NgComponentOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) directive.

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="myRandomComponent"></ng-container>
```

Ts:

```
const myComponents = [Component1, Component2, Component3]       
myRandomComponent = myComponents[Math.floor(Math.random() * (myComponents.length))]//edited
```

Comment: You were wrong a little, -1 from length leads to that all but last  elements appear as a myRandomCompoment

Comment: You're right !!

Answer (score 1):

If want to control this at bootstrap level, We can use angular bootstrap interface to achieve this.

https://angular.io/api/core/DoBootstrap

1. Remove/empty bootstrap property in app module.
2. Implement DoBootstrap interface and provide implementation to ngDoBootstrap method. Based on your business criteria, you need to decide which component has to go.
3. In index.html, body tag need to be changed like below.

   ```
   <body>  <div id="bassApp"></div></body>
   ```

**App Module Looks like this**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Component1,
    Component2,
    Component3
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap{

  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef): void {
    //based on your logic, change the component to be injected
    appRef.bootstrap(Component1, document.getElementById('bassApp'))
  }
 }
```